# Monitor multiple keyword strings in a list using PRAW

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to use PRAW to setup a bot that automatically searches keywords in the comment body of particular subreddits. The bot will then form a reply. Right now, I only have one keyword to search for. How do I make it so that it can search for multiple keywords at the same time?

```
for comment in r.subreddit('watchpeopledie+morbidreality+wtf+fearme+horriblydepressing+truecreepy+creepy+scaredshitless+test').comments(limit=25):
    if "eyebleach" in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
        print "String with \"eye bleach\" found in comment " + comment.id + "!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to define a search pattern that contains multiple keywords.

```
import re
pattern = r"\beye\s?bleach|\bcat\b|\dog\b"
match = r.search(pattern, comment.body)
if match:
    do stuff
```

This example searches 'comment.body' for the keywords "eyebleach", "eye bleach", "cat" and "dog". '\b' is for a whitespace character, so we are actually looking for " eyebleach " surrounded by spaces. 
match = True if any one of these words is found.